# String concatenation with null-coalescing operator

Tags: c#, string-concatenation

I was trying to build a string like the following and I noticed that it gets cut off after using the ?? operator, regardless of whether the previous value is null.

```
"Some Text" + System.Environment.NewLine +
varOne.ToString() ?? string.Empty + System.Environment.NewLine +
varTwo.ToString()...
```

All that the string contains (regardless of the values) is up to varOne (Some Text + newline + varOne) unless I remove the ?? operator. After looking around a bit I see that this is not the preferred way of doing this and that I should probably use a stringbuilder instead but I was just curious as to why this happens?

Comment: If a variable is `null`, calling `ToString` on it will throw.

Comment: There's no class in the framework that return `null` from `ToString` and i doubt that it's a good idea to do so. So the null-coalescing operator after `ToString` makes no sense. Maybe this: `varOne == null ? string.Empty + System.Environment.NewLine : varOne.ToString()`

Comment: Perhaps some additional parentheses might help. `??` has a lower precedence than `+`. Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [?? Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22??_CSHARPKEYWORD%22%29;k%28%22??%22%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to
>   define a default value for nullable value types or reference types. It
>   returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it
>   returns the right operand.

This implies, stuff after `??` is only assigned, if stuff before it is null.

So

```
        string sNull = null;
        string s = sNull ?? "TADA";
```

`s` would be `TADA`

and

```
        string sNull = null;
        string s = sNull ?? "TADA";
        string sNormal = s ?? "NOT TADA";
```

`sNormal` would also be `TADA`

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
"Some Text" + System.Environment.NewLine +
(varOne == null ? string.Empty : varOne.ToString()) + System.Environment.NewLine +
varTwo.ToString()...
```

Comment: @X.L.Ant Good solution thanks. Only reason I didn't mark as answer is I wanted to understand why it didn't work, not just code to fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

`varOne.ToString()` is never `null`. And suppose we have `a ?? b + c + d ?? n`, if `a != null` the whole thing eveluates to `a` and not `a + (d ?? n)` (because of operators precedence)

Answer (score 1):

The ?? operator means "if the thing before this operator is not null, use it, otherwise use the thing after this operator".

What you might be getting confused by is what constitutes "the thing before this operator". In your case, it's the whole of this:

```
"Some Text" + System.Environment.NewLine + varOne.ToString()
```

That's never going to be null. Even if varOne.ToString() returned null (which would be a bug in varOne's class, since ToString() should never return null), the result of concatenating a string with null is the original string. There's absolutely no situation in which the above could result in null.

Now, *varOne* could be null, and in that case you'd get an exception. It's possible that this is what you think you're guarding against, but it isn't the case. If that's really what you want, you'd need something like this:

```
"Some Text" + System.Environment.NewLine +
(varOne != null ? varOne.ToString() : string.Empty) + System.Environment.NewLine +
varTwo.ToString()...
```

This checks that varOne is not null, uses varOne.ToString if it isn't, and falls back to string.Empty if it is.

Note that I've avoided the whole issue of this coding style versus the use of StringBuilder, since that isn't actually part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the answer has changed. You could:

```
"Some Text" + System.Environment.NewLine +
// no need to coalesce because concatenating nulls are ignored
varOne?.ToString() 
System.Environment.NewLine + varTwo.ToString()
```

or even

```
$"Some Text{System.Environment.NewLine}{varOne}{System.Environment.NewLine}{varTwo}"
// If you're not writing to a system-dependent file, \r\n will also work fine:
$"Some Text\r\n{varOne}\r\n{varTwo}"
```